# Calling window.open through port

Tags: elm

I'm implementing social auth. When the user clicks on a button, I send a command so I can call `window.open()`.

Looking at this call-stack, we can see that the port handler is called in the next event loop:
[image]

Since `window.open` is not being called within the click event lifecycle, browsers like safari do not allow for the popup to show up.

What is your approach?

Comment: Could you create an [iframe](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#iframe) overlay in Elm with the src set to the relevant login page?

Comment: @SimonH nah, it's a [security concern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9089070/592641)

Comment: Are you using some sort of event batching framework?  Calling window.open through a port in a click handler does work normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not super pretty, but you can do something like

```
a 
    [ Html.Attributes.attribute "onClick" "window.open(this.href, this.target, 'width=800,height=600'); return false;" ]
    [ text "Click me" ]
```

Comment: until we get control of whether should the command wait for the next event loop, this is the most straightforward way

Answer (score 1):

It's an underhanded way to handle this, and not 100% strictly guaranteed to continue working in future elm releases but I've done this more than once in a pinch:

https://medium.com/@prozacchiwawa/the-i-m-stupid-elm-language-nugget-7-8d3efd525e3e

A property getter on the DOM node type can be triggered by a json decoder during event handling.  You can run whatever code you want as a side effect of accessing it.  The object being accessed by the json decoder is the real event object on the event handler stack as things are now.